# click two specific buttons using sender

Tags: vb.net

so in my code below I'm trying to make it so that if I click in the first button both the first button and 2nd button will be clicked. same for player 2 but instead of the 2nd button being pressed. the one below it (so button 7) how do I do this?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim PLAYER As Integer = 1
    Dim squares(6, 6) As Button
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Public Sub New()



        For x = 1 To 6
            For y = 1 To 6
                squares(x, y) = New Button
                With squares(x, y)
                    .Top = (100 + 100 * (x - 1))
                    .Left = (100 + 100 * (y - 1))
                    .Width = 100
                    .Height = 100
                    .Text = ""
                    AddHandler squares(x, y).Click, AddressOf square_click
                End With
                Me.Controls.Add(squares(x, y))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
    Sub square_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If PLAYER = 1 Then
            sender.backcolor = Color.OrangeRed
            sender.enabled = False
            PLAYER += 1

            ElseIf PLAYER = 2 Then
                sender.backcolor = Color.LimeGreen
            sender.enabled = False
            PLAYER -= 1
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. Could you explain better what should happen when a player clicks on a button?

Comment: Simulate/call a Click on a button You can just use:  `squares(index1, index2).PerformClick()` .  That allows to generate an `Control.Click`  `Event`

Answer (score 0):

You need some mechanism to derive the location of the button you have clicked. You could use the button's `Location` property for that, but personally I would suggest that you put a `Point` with the `X` and `Y` coordinates in the button's `Tag` property.

In the button click event handler, you could read the button's `Tag` property. For player 1, you need to increase X with 1 and for player 2, you need to increase Y with 1. If X respectively Y is 6, you cannot increase it anymore; I assume you want to jump back to 1 in that case.

Below is my solution. Notice that I use 0-based indexes: I start counting at 0, not at 1. That keeps various calculations easy.

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim PLAYER As Integer = 1
  Dim squares(5, 5) As Button

  Public Sub New()
    For x As Integer = 0 To 5
      For y As Integer = 0 To 5
        Dim btn As New Button()

        btn.Top = 100 + 100 * y
        btn.Left = 100 + 100 * x
        btn.Width = 100
        btn.Height = 100

        btn.Tag = New Point(x, y)

        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick

        squares(x, y) = btn
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
      Next
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim pos As Point = CType(btn.Tag, Point)

    If PLAYER = 1 Then
      btn.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
      btn.Enabled = False

      Dim otherButton As Button = squares((pos.X + 1) Mod 6, pos.Y)

      otherButton.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
      otherButton.Enabled = False

      PLAYER = 2
    Else
      btn.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
      btn.Enabled = False

      Dim otherButton As Button = squares(pos.X, (pos.Y + 1) Mod 6)

      otherButton.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
      otherButton.Enabled = False

      PLAYER = 1
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```